# How to create a report on all Governor limits in my org

Tags: governorlimits

Do we have any way to get all Governor limits in my org e.g. Number of Objects, fields, workflow, validation rules, storage limits etc. I am interested in creating a report saying how soon am I going to exhaust the governor limits.

For each object, salesforce create a 'Object Limit' section. Is there any way we can access that object.

I know we can use Schema class to count fields for each objects. But still there will be a lot of overhead to calculate each limit manually.

Answer (score 2):

Some of governor limit only appear during the transaction so I think it impossible to track it in report.For example , when user run update on Opportunity -- some governor limit only fire upon that transaction.This can be tracked by developer in coding by checking limit before performing the operation.

For other , you can check System overview .Go to Setup --> System Overview which it can shows you important usage data and limits about your organization .

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes I know that we can track the transactional limit only on run time. My question is to track the edition limits like number of custom objects.

Comment: refer to answer. You can check custom object , maximum allowed, total of current custom object.